# What is the meaning of breaking code while implementing new features?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I was reading a text about SOLID principles and Open/Close principle and it said that : "The main idea of this principle is to keep existing code from breaking when you implement new features"

**what it means by breaking code?**

Comment: "keep existing code from breaking" in that case means that existing code should work just like it did before. The added new changes should not suddenly result in  existing code giving wrong results or no longer working in any other way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ - probably.

Comment: Note: by tagging a question like this with `java`, you expose it to a lot of people who know about the tags they follow, but don't know the answer.  Some of them will downvote it or close-vote it as a result.

Comment: "breaking" in this context means "introducing bugs." As in "The main idea of this principle is to prevent the introduction of bugs in existing code when you implement new features."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "break" existing code when you modify it in a way that prevents it from working for existing or intended use cases, when it worked fine for those use cases before you modified it.

By writing your code so that it is open for extension, but closed for modification, you allow the code to be used in new situations without having to modify it.  No modification = no breaking.